# what happens in a &= -a with Java

Tags: java, bit

I see this comment, but don't understand it.

Get its last set bit

```
diff &= -diff;
```

I tried

```
int a = 3 & -3; it returns 1.
int a = 2 & -2; it returns 2.
int a = 4 & -4; it returns 4.
int a = 5 & -5; it returns 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment would be better expressed as 'Get the least significant bit set'. To understand what is going on, you need to examine how negative numbers are represented in binary. The technique is called twos complement and works by starting with the positive representation of the number; you  complement each bit (i.e. 1 -> 0 and 0 -> 1). You then add 1 to this number. In the example of 12:

```
00001100 12
11110011 complement
00000001 binary 1
11110100 add to complement to form twos complement negative
```

If you now AND the original value with the negative, you get

```
00000100
```

where the only bit set corresponds to the least significant bit set in the original pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, `diff & -diff` returns the value of the last bit that was set on diff. For example:

```
diff = 14
.... = 1110 (binary)
....     ^ last set bit
.... 10 is the last set bit
.... 10 in decimal is 2
```

Another example

```
diff = 24
.... = 11000 (binary)
....    ^ last set bit
.... 1000 is the last set bit
.... 1000 in decimal is 8
```